# MySQL, MySQL Workbench, MAMP, and Eclipse

Tags: php, mysql, database, eclipse, mysql-workbench

I am an extremely under-experienced web developer who is attempting to create a website with a couple friends. The front end stuff is all taken care of and I have been assigned to handle the back end stuff. My background is Materials Engineering, so needless to say, my programming experience relative to back end web development is non-existent. The questions I am going to ask will likely be trivial, and might not make sense at all!

I am just going to try and gain any understanding of the dynamics between MySQL, MAMP, and Eclipse.

1. If I use the tools provided by MAMP (phpMyAdmin) to create databases, do I then have to incorporate code into our front end code to get it to talk to the databases?
2. Is MySQLWorkbench a viable option to create the databases? If it is, and I create the databases and extract the code for the databases, where would this code go?

I guess I am just trying to obtain general knowledge on how to create and incorporate databases with MAMP and eclipse, when using MySQL as a database. Again, I understand this is probably trivial, so I would appreciate any information that can be provided!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, eclipse is simply an IDE (Integrated Development Environment), rather it is a tool that can be used to help develop your code, make sure that you are following proper syntax, etc. It is not however, a replacement for knowing a programming language.

That said, MAMP (Mac, Apache, MySQL, & PHP) is an application stack. Macintosh being the operating system, Apache being the web server that serves up your web pages, PHP being the back end programming language that (potentially) compiles the pages that Apache Servers, and MySQL being the database from which PHP pulls the data from.

As far as creating your databases, PhpMyAdmin and MySQL Workbench are both tools for helping you accomplish the task of creating your databases, tables, and potentially inserting data into these tables. However, as mentioned above you will need to use PHP or some other language, to connect to these databases and pull the information. I highly recommend checking out the PHP [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [PDO MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) libraries.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Would the PHP used to connect to these databases also dictate how the information is stored within the database? My understanding of how the information is given to the database is murky.

Comment: Furthermore, if I just wanted to set up a simple database where I manually put in information (just to see if it works), would I write the PHP code to do so, in eclipse? This code would be in eclipse for the purpose of talking to my database which was set up in MAMP. Is that generally how it works?

Comment: Information can be given to the database or retrieved from the database via php (See the documentation I referenced via hyperlink). Personally I use a tool such as phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench to set up my databases and populate with any initial data needed. PHP meerly provides a bridge to close the gap between getting what the web user sees and what is in the database.